# My App created with "create-react-app" shows up in Desktop and Mobile, but not Mobile iOS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53, amazon-cloudfront

I'm currently creating my Web Development Services Website and I created it using create-react-app. The website works properly in Desktop and Mobile Phone. The only problem I have is that the website does not show up in iPhone 6S (neither Chrome or Safari). I was looking trough internet but I couldn't fin any answer to it. I hope to get any answer. I honestly do not know where to start, but all of the code is located in this github repo: https://github.com/luisenriquecgongora/oracliom-website
The website is hosted in AWS S3, and the content is delivered using CloudFront and Route 53. The website is www.oracliom.com

I already tried to include this header in the cache:

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0" />
```

I also tried cleaning the cache of the mobile phone.

THE FULL CODE IS LOCATED HERE: https://github.com/luisenriquecgongora/oracliom-website

Answer (score 0):

try installing :
`npm i core-js raf`

then in index.js

`import 'core-js/fn/number/is-nan'; import 'core-js/es7/'; import 'core-js/es6/'; import 'raf/polyfill';`

ref: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/4844